# upload image with soundcloud api

Tags: ruby, soundcloud, image-uploading, user-profile, avatar

I keep getting an error everytime I try to change the souncloud avatar by uploading, I'm guessing something is wrong with my api wrapper layout? I get a

> "`handle_response': HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error (SoundCloud::ResponseError)"
>
> "HTTP status: 403 Forbidden (SoundCloud::ResponseError)
>       from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:32:in `post'"

My code:

```
require 'soundcloud'

user = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => '...',
                    :client_secret => '...',
                    :username => '...',
                    :password => '...')


avatar_data = File.path("/path/to/file/-1.jpg")

user.post('/me').avatar_data
```

I also tried:

```
testuser.post('/me/#{avatar_data}')
```

Comment: is that ok, that you calling your `avatar_data` method after you made post request?

Comment: I think you should check your connecting data - client_id, client_secret, etc. The most likely reason for this. And error occurs [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby/blob/master/lib/soundcloud/client.rb#L33).

Comment: I think they work fine though... @GenaShumilkin

Comment: yeah you're right @Avdept , I've been trying multiple api wrappers trying to figure it out because I haven't seen an example anywhere on the net that shows you how. :\

Comment: @marriedjane875 Actually I recommend to use [REST-client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and to work with Soundclouds's API directly, without using strange narrowly used gem. This the is universal way.

Comment: ok that sounds better @GenaShumilkin I'll start learning to use that gem and hopefully that will help. Thanks :)

Comment: also, what if I have muliple users of a certain cite, can/will the rest-client gem be able to handle every specified user? @GenaShumilkin

Comment: @marriedjane875 yes, sure

Comment: Idk how to search what i'm looking for with the REST-client gem @GenaShumilkin